# register any click on href on entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to register any click on href on entire page.

for an example user click on below href.

```
<a href="/abc">abc<a/>
```

Then I should be able to get anchor tag.

```
<span hre="/abc">abc</span>
```

Then I should be able to get anchor tag. To get anchor tag, i have written the below jQuery.

```
$(this).on("click", "a", function(){});
```

but this only works for anchor tag, i want it to work for any tag like span or div who is clickable.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Are you trying to swap the element from an `a` to a `span` on successive clicks?

Comment: no, see anchor tag has href attribute so its clickable and my span have also a href attribute. what should i write to generalize way so i can handle any click event on page, currently my code works for only anchor tag.

Comment: That doesn't really clear up the confusion. `span` elements cannot have `href` attributes. If you want to redirect the page when an element is clicked, use `a` elements only

Comment: If your span has `href=` tag, then your span is malformed.

Comment: i agree with your comment, but somehow someone have already added href for span and i dnt want to change that code.

Comment: Well, better use classes, but if you insist :
  $("body").on("click", "*[href]", function(){});

Comment: classes are dynamic, i mean it can be change in future so i don't want to depend on classes. got the solution but is it preferable or not.now this is the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can use `$( "*" )` selector to catch every elt of the page (cf: [All selector](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)), if you add attribute selector like `[href]`, you'll get all elt that have attribute Href.

```
$("body").on("click", "*[href]", function(){});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Answer (score 1):

To select anything with a href attribute, you can use the attribute selector.. `[attribute]`..

eg.

```js
$("body").on("click", "[href]", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).text() + " = " + $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span href="123">Span With href</span><br>
<a href="345">Anchor tag with href</a>
<div href="888">Div with href</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pickup any click on any tag with an href attribute:

```
$("[href]").click(function() {...`
```

Or

```
$(document).on("click", "[href]", function() {...`
```

to also include dynamic elements (added after the jquery code has run).

---

For *anything that's clickable*, then :

```
$(document).on("click", function(event) { 
    var target = event.target;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$(this).on("click", "a", function(){});
```

you can use an wildcard selector:

```
$(this).on("click", "*", function(){});
```

or an attribute selector if you want to select items having the `href` attribute:

```
$(this).on("click", "[href]", function(){});
```

But this code is not a good idea:

```
<span hre="/abc">abc</span>
```

since a `span` should not have a `href`. And you misspelled `href`, you typed only `hre` instead.